# 2 container side by side one fixed one dynamic height

Tags: html, css, vertical-alignment

Have a look at the jsFiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/sg7u3exf/

I want these divs to be exactly like this but without this part

```
top: 50%;
margin-top: -100px;
```

because it causes the divs to go out of the view field once its too small.

I also like to change the fixed div to be on top of the other and not fixed anymore once the window is smaller.

at best without the need of javascript.

I'd also like the dynamic height div to create height for the body, since i have a background image div which has to be the whole height of the page.

**Edit:
after all I found a solution with a media Query: https://jsfiddle.net/sg7u3exf/6/**

Answer (score 0):

You can replace the CSS section in your question with:

```
top: calc(50% - 100px);
```

That gets rid of the negative margin that you wanted to remove.

I'm not sure how that helps you though. ([Here's the modified fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sg7u3exf/1/))

Comment: Well that's has the same problem as before since the content goes out of the view field when the window size is too small. Maybe I'll remove the last part of the question :-)

Answer (score 0):

```css
.wrapper {
    text-align: center;
    position:absolute;
    top:50%;
    left:50%
}
.leftFixed {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100px;
    height: 200px;
    background-color: red;
    
    /* just to demonstrate */
    position: fixed;    
    margin-left: -55px;
}
.rightDynamicScrolled {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100px;
    background-color: green;
    
    /* just to demonstrate */
    position: relative;
    margin-left: 55px;    
}
```

Hii dude you can check after putting this css changes into your jsfiddle

and one thing  you need to apply at-least **top:**  to the respective wrapper class to look exactly like you have show in you demo jsfiddle so take a look here with updated jsfiddle

and yes one thing that is you can set left and top to as per your need.

[check Updated jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sg7u3exf/2/)

Comment: Well that doesn't center the two divs

Comment: @LiKeLights then you can adjust the top: 's percentage value

Comment: but that will never center the divs just at a specific screen width and height.